# 32-bit deterministic Miller-Rabin primality test

Tags: c#, mathematics

Are there any ways in which this code could be improved? I'm particularly interested in the `ModularExponentiation` function as it is the primary bottleneck during performance testing. Replacing the built-in modulus operator with ["FastMod"](https://lemire.me/blog/2019/02/08/faster-remainders-when-the-divisor-is-a-constant-beating-compilers-and-libdivide/) improves things slightly but I'm curious if there are better ways to implement the algorithm.

```
public static bool IsPrime(this uint value) {
    if (0U == (value & 01U)) { return (02U == value); }
    if (0U == (value % 03U)) { return (03U == value); }
    if (0U == (value % 05U)) { return (05U == value); }
    if (0U == (value % 07U)) { return (07U == value); }
    if (0U == (value % 11U)) { return (11U == value); }
    if (0U == (value % 13U)) { return (13U == value); }
    if (0U == (value % 17U)) { return (17U == value); }
    if (0U == (value % 19U)) { return (19U == value); }
    if (0U == (value % 23U)) { return (23U == value); }
    if (0U == (value % 29U)) { return (29U == value); }
    if (0U == (value % 31U)) { return (31U == value); }
    if (0U == (value % 37U)) { return (37U == value); }
    if (0U == (value % 41U)) { return (41U == value); }
    if (0U == (value % 43U)) { return (43U == value); }
    if (0U == (value % 47U)) { return (47U == value); }
    if (0U == (value % 53U)) { return (53U == value); }
    if (0U == (value % 59U)) { return (59U == value); }
    if (0U == (value % 61U)) { return (61U == value); }
    if (0U == (value % 67U)) { return (67U == value); }
    if (0U == (value % 71U)) { return (71U == value); }
    if (0U == (value % 73U)) { return (73U == value); }
    if (0U == (value % 79U)) { return (79U == value); }
    if (0U == (value % 83U)) { return (83U == value); }
    if (0U == (value % 89U)) { return (89U == value); }
    if (0U == (value % 97U)) { return (97U == value); }

    var exponent = (value - 1U);
    var multiplier = GetModuloMultiplier(divisor: value);
    var shift = ((int)uint.TrailingZeroCount(value: exponent));

    exponent >>= shift;

    return (
        IsStrongPseudoprime(@base: 02U, exponent: exponent, multiplier: multiplier, shift: shift, value: value) &&
        IsStrongPseudoprime(@base: 07U, exponent: exponent, multiplier: multiplier, shift: shift, value: value) &&
        IsStrongPseudoprime(@base: 61U, exponent: exponent, multiplier: multiplier, shift: shift, value: value) &&
        (1U != value)
    );

    static UInt128 GetModuloMultiplier(ulong divisor) =>
        ((UInt128.MaxValue / divisor) + UInt128.One);
    static bool IsStrongPseudoprime(uint @base, uint exponent, UInt128 multiplier, int shift, uint value) {
        var valueMinusOne = (value - 1U);
        var witness = ModularExponentiation(@base: @base, exponent: exponent, modulus: value, multiplier: multiplier);

        if ((1U != witness) && (valueMinusOne != witness)) {
            var index = 0;

            while (++index < shift) {
                witness = ((uint)Modulo(divisor: value, multiplier: multiplier, value: ((ulong)witness * witness)));

                if ((1U == witness)) { return false; }
                if (valueMinusOne == witness) { break; }
            }

            if (index == shift) { return false; }
        }

        return true;
    }
    static uint ModularExponentiation(uint @base, uint exponent, uint modulus, UInt128 multiplier) {
        var a = ((ulong)@base);
        var d = 1UL;

        do {
            if (0U != (exponent & 1U)) {
                d = Modulo(divisor: modulus, multiplier: multiplier, value: (a * d));
            }

            a = Modulo(divisor: modulus, multiplier: multiplier, value: (a * a));
        } while (0U != (exponent >>= 1));

        return ((uint)d);
    }
    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
    static ulong Modulo(ulong divisor, UInt128 multiplier, ulong value) =>
        ((ulong)(((((multiplier * value) >> (sizeof(ulong) * 8)) + UInt128.One) * divisor) >> (sizeof(ulong) * 8)));
}
```

Comment: I guess you meant to link to [Faster remainders when the divisor is a constant](https://lemire.me/blog/2019/02/08/faster-remainders-when-the-divisor-is-a-constant-beating-compilers-and-libdivide/)? The post about an *alternative* to modulo reduction in the context of hash tables does not offer a replacement after all, it does something else that also works as a range reduction, but it doesn't work for any other purpose.

Comment: @harold You are correct, thanks! I have fixed the error.

Comment: The three calls to IsStrongPsedoprime with different constant input (base) seem interesting. Which call is faster? Common cases? What happens if you "inline" those constants? By attributes or e.g. ModularExponentiationWithBase2?

Comment: @Andreas See [here](https://miller-rabin.appspot.com/). All three bases must be tested in order to be certain that the value is prime. Can you elaborate on what you mean by inlining the constants?

Comment: @Kittoes0124 `ModularExponentiation` will be called with bases 2, 7, and 61. By "inlining constants" I mean each call should have their own code paths, by aggressive inlining attribute or separate functions. Perhaps the compiler can optimize base 2 better than base 7.

Comment: @Kittoes0124 " if there are better ways to implement the algorithm." --> are the values random or select (likely prime, likely not-prime)?

Comment: @Kittoes0124 Are you concerned about potential overflow in `a*a` and `a*d`?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica there shouldn't be any potential, `a` and `d` both fit in 32 bits (due to being reduced modulo some 32 bit number) so their product fits in 64 bits. Unless there's a bug in `Modulo`, which would break that property.

Comment: @harold OK......

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Good question, but I am not. `a` and `d` are cast from `uint` to `ulong` in order to ensure that the product will not overflow.

Answer (score 1):

Your early exit statements are really repetitive.

Here is an alternative solution:

````
static uint[] divisors = new[] { 03U, 05U, 07U, ..., 97U }; 
public static bool IsPrime(this uint value)
{
    if (0U == (value & 1U))
        return 2U == value;

    foreach (var divisor in divisors)
    {
        if (0U == (value % divisor))
            return divisor == value; 
    }

    ...
}
```
````

Comment: That creates a new problem though: the remainder-by-constant expressions would be optimized, but this remainder-by-variable won't be. You can do it manually, using the "multiply by modular multiplicative inverse, then compare" trick.

Comment: @harold This solution prefers maintainability over performance.

Comment: You may as well remove that whole section of the algorithm (not the test for even numbers, that's required), even more maintainable. The only thing it does is speed up the average time, the three MR tests are sufficient.

Comment: @harold has a point, the early returns were added because they make a very big performance difference. Removing them will not affect the accuracy of the test.

Answer (score 0):

Corner case bug: If `exponent = 0, modulus == 1`, `ModularExponentiation(base, 0, 1, multiplier)` returns 1 where 0 is expected.

Consider `var d = 1UL;` --> `var d = 1UL%base;` or the like.